# Can I disable browser cache in Visual Studio 2012 Page Inspector?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

I am trying to update a LESS file but when I refresh the rendered page in Page Inspector in Visual Studio 2012 it doesn't load my changes. If I open the same page in Internet Explorer and press Ctrl + F5 Internet Explorer will load my changes, then if I go back to Page Inspector and refresh the changes display there as well. I tried holding Ctrl and then pressing the refresh button in Page Inspector but that didn't load either.